# Error: 'xxx' is not a type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

In this complete code:

```c++
class foo
{
  public:
    foo(const int pin);
};

class bar {
  public:
    // Constructor
    bar(const int dataPin) : dataPin_ (dataPin) { }

  private:
    const int dataPin_;
    foo myFoo_ (dataPin_);  // instance of foo
};

int main (void)
  {
  return 0;
  }
```

Using g++ 4.8.4 I get the error:

```
g++ -Wall -c "test.cpp" (in directory: /home/nick/Development)
test.cpp:14:17: error: ‘dataPin_’ is not a type
     foo myFoo_ (dataPin_);  // instance of foo
                 ^
Compilation failed.
```

Using clang 3.4-1ubuntu3 I get:

```
test.cpp:14:17: error: unknown type name 'dataPin_'
    foo myFoo_ (dataPin_);  // instance of foo
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Why does it want a type here? This is attempting to create an instance of `foo` as a class variable of `bar`. The variable `dataPin_` is declared directly above.

---

If I change the line with the error to this, it compiles cleanly:

```c++
    foo myFoo_ (int dataPin_);  // instance of foo
```

Comment: You have to initialise `myFoo_` in the `bar()` constructor like any other member of the class.

Comment: Even if you turn on C++11, using parens for in-class data member initialization still isn't allowed (as opposed to braces or =).

Comment: foo myFoo_ (dataPin_);  // instance of foo.  Is that supposed to be a function or variable?

Comment: That line is supposed to be a variable - an instance of `foo`.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate personally. I didn't ask about in-class initializers, and the "duplicate" question certainly did not appear when I searched for that error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's reading `foo myFoo_ (dataPin_);` as a function declaration: `myFoo_` is a function taking a `dataPin_` and returning a `foo`. That's why it's expecting a type name in `(` `)`.

To fix this, initialize `myFoo_` in your constructor, just like you did with `dataPin_`:

```
bar(const int dataPin) : dataPin_ (dataPin), myFoo_(dataPin) {}
```

Comment: OK, I see it now. The "fix" I used merely turned the line into a function prototype. What you suggested compiled OK - along with changing the line in error to merely: `foo myFoo_; `

Answer (score -1):

Here you should add type not variable, this is the function signature, it should has types not variables.

```
foo myFoo_ (dataPin_);  // instance of foo
```

Comment: "Here you should add type not variable" doesn't answer the question "Why does it want a type here?", it just repeats what the compiler said.

Comment: I was editing it to explain more, and then I saw your answer, so I left it as I was going to say the same as you :) . @melpomene